# how to use use advanced time calculations with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I moved to codeigniter and before i did my sql query worked but now that im on a framework it doesnt. im trying to round time and here is my query:

```
SELECT
                                    DATE_FORMAT(wo.dateCreated,'%m/%d/%Y @ %h:%i %p') AS dateCreated
                                    , wo.id
                                    , sr.id AS srid
                                    , ROUND((TIME_TO_SEC(sr.endtime) -
                                                    TIME_TO_SEC(sr.starttime)) / 3600.0 , 2 ) AS totalHours
                                                                        , ROUND((TIME_TO_SEC(sr.endtime) -
                                             TIME_TO_SEC(sr.starttime)) / 3600.0 , 2 ) - sr.deduction AS deductHours
                                    , l.name AS locationName
                                    , l.address
                                    , l.zip
                                FROM company AS c
```

I shortened the query so it wouldnt be so long, bascially i just need to know how to properly do the ROUND part using codeigniter. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
I changed per your suggestion which gives me this:

```
public function get_sr($id) {

    $this->db->select('
                        sr.id
                       ,sr.woid
                       ,sr.description
                       ,sr.techId
                       ,sr.startTime
                       ,sr.endTime
                       ,ROUND((TIME_TO_SEC(sr.endtime) - TIME_TO_SEC(sr.starttime)) / 3600.0 , 2 ) AS totalHours
                       ,u.first_name
                       ,u.last_name
                       ,rt.value AS rate
                       ,wo.tid');
    $this->db->from('service_report sr');
    $this->db->join('work_orders wo','wo.id = sr.woid','left');
    $this->db->join('enum_rate_type rt','rt.id = sr.rateType','left');
    $this->db->join('users u','u.id = sr.techId','left');
    $this->db->where('sr.woid', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
```

but now i get an error when calling it: 
Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object

without the ROUND line, it displays fine.

here is my view:

```
                        <?php
                        $total = 0;
                        foreach ($srInfo as $row):
                        $total += $amount = $row['rate'] * $row['deductHours'];
                        ?>

            <tbody>
                <!-- Cart item -->

                <tr>
                    <td class="center"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>

                    <td>
                        <h5><?php echo $row['description']; ?></h5>
                    </td>

                    <td class="center"><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?> <?php echo $row['last_name']; ?></td>

                    <td class="center"><?php echo $row['deductHours']; ?></td>

                    <td class="center"><?php echo "$" . number_format($total, 2); ?></td>


                </tr><!-- // Cart item END -->
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: are you using `active record`?

Comment: post the model code hoe you are running the query

Comment: edited to add my model and view

Comment: The names in the query don't match the names in your view. Please make sure the code you show makes sense or it will be very difficult to answer your question. I suggest you try using the [`query`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html) function instead of Active Record for this one.

Comment: they match in my controller, like i said everything works when i take the ROUND line out, im just trying to get the ROUND statement correct.

Comment: Like I said: try using the `query` function instead of Active Record. I don't know what the controller has to do with this? I am just pointing out that `deductHours` from your view is nowhere to be seen in the query and `totalHours` from the query is nowhere to be seen in the view. This is sloppy and confusing for people trying to answer your question. You might as well leave out the view code altogether.